# Not sure how to update a single customers records. VB.net

Tags: database, vb.net, vb.net-2010

When I get rid of the 'where' in the SQL statement it works but overwrites all the data, however, I can't get it to work with only one specific customer. Could someone show me where I am going wrong thanks.

Private Sub Save_but_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Save_but.Click

```
    Dim sqlcmd As New OleDbCommand
    cn.Open()
    sqlcmd.Connection = cn
    sqlcmd.CommandText = "Update TblCustomers Set CFName= @CFName, CSName = @CSName, Caddress= @Caddress,"
    sqlcmd.CommandText &= "CTelNo = CTelNo WHERE CustID = @PublicCustID"
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", TxtFirstName.Text)
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CName", TxtSurname.Text)
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Caddress", TxtAddress.Text)
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CTelNo", TxtTelNo.Text)
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CustomerId", PublicCustID)

    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    cn.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Customer information has been updated.", PublicCustID)
```

Comment: You never set the value of the `@PublicCustID` parameter

Comment: how would i do that

Comment: The same way you're setting the value of all the other ones... `sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PublicCustID", PublicCustID)`

Comment: @StevenDoggart it is set as a sting in the main module but that about it

Comment: alright ill try that now thanks

Comment: `PublicCustID` is just a variable in your application, it's not the SQL parameter.  You need to tell it what the value of the SQL parameter is.

Comment: @StevenDoggart just tried that doesnt seem to work here is what it looks like right now :

Comment: sqlcmd.CommandText &= "CTelNo = CTelNo WHERE CustID = @PublicCustID"
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", TxtFirstName.Text)
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CName", TxtSurname.Text)
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Caddress", TxtAddress.Text)
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CTelNo", TxtTelNo.Text)

        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PublicCustID", PublicCustID)

Comment: I've figured out the other problem, I forgot to add an '@',  thanks a lot for the help @StevenDoggart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Add the parameter for  @PublicCustID 
before executenonQuery

```
 sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PublicCustID", yourPublicCustID)
```

Remove line

```
 sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CustomerId", PublicCustID)
```